# Combine tuples in a list which have the same value

Tags: python, tuples, equivalence-classes

I have a list with tuples like this:

```
L ={(1,2), (1,4), (1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (6,7)}
```

I try to combine these to get equivalence classes (tuples of the same value are merged, like (1,2) and (2,3) becomes (1,2,3)). So you get:

```
EQ = {(1,2,3,4,5), (6,7)}
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: How (1,2) and (3,5) get in the same bucket?

Comment: @Andrey because of (1,3)

Comment: @fredtantini so it is not about "equivalence classes", it is some weird transitive aggregation.

Comment: @Andrey equivalence has transitivity and symmetry no?

Comment: @fredtantini it is not how classification works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following recursion function . first you can convert the elements to `set` and go though the set and check any element with the elements after if , when you find an element that have any intersection (`v & k`) you merg thous set together and remove the second element from list and update the main list  :

```
L ={(1,2), (1,4), (1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (6,7)}
s=[set(i) for i in L if i]

def find_intersection(m_list):
    for i,v in enumerate(m_list) : 
        for j,k in enumerate(m_list[i+1:],i+1):  
           if v & k:
              s[i]=v.union(m_list.pop(j))
              return find_intersection(m_list)
    return m_list


print find_intersection(s)
```

result :

```
[set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), set([6, 7])]
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Note that in the second `enumerate` function i use i+1 for the start number for indexing of `m_list[i+1:]` because of that the index of k (j) be equal with the index of k in main list.